# system login using query select 1

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, vb.net-module

I am trying to code the login page, here is my code:

```
'login form code
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click

        Dim username As String = txtUsername.Text.Trim
        Dim pwd As String = txtPassword.Text.Trim
        Dim insertQry As String = "select 1 from UserInfo where username = '" & username & "' and userpassword = '" & pwd & "'"  
        Dim res As Boolean = executeReader(insertQry)
End Sub

database module

Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Module DBconn
    Public conn_ As New SqlConnection("")   

    Public Function executeReader(ByVal query As String)
        Try
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query, conn_)
            conn_.Open()
            Dim r2 As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function

End Module
```

My question is how to do validation of username and password check with select 1 query?

Comment: You should be calling `ExecuteScalar`, not `ExecuteReader`.

Comment: Also, you should learn how to use parameters in ADO.NET. Yoru code would allow a malicious user to delete all your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this example, it does the following:

1. It returns the count of the primary key value in the SQL query ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql))
2. It uses parameters to pass the values to the WHERE clause ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add))
3. It uses ExecuteScalar to return a single value from the command ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar))

```vb
Private Function ValidateLogin(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String) As Boolean
    Dim count As Integer = 0

    'Declare the connection object
    Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection

        'Wrap code in Try/Catch
        Try
            'Set the connection string
            con.ConnectionString = "" 'TODO: set this value

            'Create a new instance of the command object
            Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT Count(UserInfoId) FROM UserInfo WHERE username=@username AND userpassword=@password", con)

                'Parameterize the query
                With cmd.Parameters
                    .Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = username
                    .Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = password
                End With

                'Open the connection
                con.Open()

                'Use ExecuteScalar to return a single value
                count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())

                'Close the connection
                con.Close()
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Display the error
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        Finally
            'Check if the connection object was initialized
            If con IsNot Nothing Then
                If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                    'Close the connection if it was left open(exception thrown)
                    con.Close()
                End If
            End If
        End Try
    End Using

    'Return row count is greater than 0
    Return count > 0
End Function
```